# Latex warning package pgfheaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, warnings

I have a latex beamer file for a presentation, however, running the file creats the following warning and no pdf is created at all
package pgfheaps warning. this package is obsolete. on input line 16.
What does this mean please?
Thanks a lot for your help.
Sanaa Moussa

Comment: it is not a generic warning, the file itself has been edited by its author to say `\PackageWarning{pgfheaps}{This package is obsolete.}`  usually if package authors do something like this they make the warning say what to use instead but not here. As this is part of the base pgf distribution I assume pgf itself has suitable facilities now so this little extension package was given this warning, but I can not tell you  what to use instead so not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

PGF has been restructured quite a bit since 2006 and the functionality this piece of library offers is already available with regular commands and node placement on curves. Your file must be really really old to have this library mentioned. Or your beamer version is exceedingly old that still uses `pgfheaps`. But still it is not the cause of no PDF file produced error.

However, if it is that old, many packages could be conflicting anyways. Best is to try it on a new version of `beamer` and see whether it flies or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I haven't used beamer years ago, that's why I know you are right telling it is very old. My question now, if you please, how to get the latest verion of beamer?

Comment: @user402254 If you update your TeX distro (TeXLive or MikTeX) then you would get a recent version of everything)